# Error with loading a .pb model for prediction: Op type not registered 'DecodeProtoSparseV4'

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

By running this command to load a trained model (saved_model.pb) for doing the prediction:
model_directory = 'C:/Users/.../predict/001/'
model = tf.saved_model.load(model_directory)

I get the following error: Op type not registered 'DecodeProtoSparseV4' in binary running. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib (e.g. `tf.contrib.resampler`), accessing should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.

I changed Tensorflow version, but it did not help.